# Assign every element from a collection to multiple elements from an array

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this issue, I need to retrieve all the routes assigned to each event. I have an Event model and with the query builder I will retrieve a collection of these Events.

Each of the events (there are only 5) has a tournamentkey attribute (a string) like this :

```
$event->tournamentkey
```

On the other side I have an array of static routes like this :

```
$eventRoutes = [
            'events/{tournamentKey}/home',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/tournament-info',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/teams',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/schedule-and-results',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/standings',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/stats/general',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/editions'
        ];
```

I'd like to retrieve an array of routes having each of the $eventRoutes for an event.
I dunno if I explained myself well but, the end result should be an array of 35 routes, 7 route per Event (5 events in total).
Now this is how my code looks like, but it returns only an array with 5 routes, only the 1st route for each of the events.

```
$eventRoutes = [
            'events/{tournamentKey}/home',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/tournament-info',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/teams',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/schedule-and-results',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/standings',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/stats/general',
            'events/{tournamentKey}/editions'
        ];
        $eventMenuItems = collect();
        $events = Event::whereFederationId($federationId)->get();
        $events->each(function ($event) use ($eventRoutes, &$eventMenuItems) {
            foreach ($eventRoutes as $route) {
                $newRoutes = str_replace('{tournamentKey}', $event->tournamentkey, $route);
                $eventMenuItems->push($newRoutes);
                return $eventMenuItems;
            }
        });
```

Of course I am doing something wrong but I am struggling to find out what..

Comment: You end your anonymous callback by returning from the `foreach` loop.

Comment: So I should put the return $eventMenuItems outside the forEach, inside the each right? I dunno if I expressed myself correctly

Comment: I'm not sure you even need it since you pass that array by reference (I'm not very familiar with the functionalities of Laravel). But if it's necessary, then it should be placed after the loop.

Comment: Yeah it worked.. such a silly mistake... Thanks a lot :)